# How to provide role with files from the playbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I have a "common" role, which is basically for installing my tools on a server, including VIM theme. Now, I don't want to include this VIM theme inside the role, I would like to publish this role and allow people to install theme of their choice, so I would like to allow them to provide it using the playbook layer. I know obviously how to pass to role variables from the playbook, but how to approach the problem of other resources, like files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative paths in your role and expect those files to be in the playbook directory and not necessary in `roles/myrole/files` subfolder.

For example a task in your role:

```
- copy: src=test.txt dest=/tmp/
```

and this structure:

```
./playbook.yml
./test.txt
./roles/myrole/tasks/main.yml
```

will successfully find `test.txt` and copy it to `/tmp` directory.